# duplicate no-repeat value for background-repeat in Table dialog

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, background-repeat

I am using CKEditor and having issues with no-repeat value of background-property being duplicated.

Steps

- Insert table
- Right click, Table Properties, then go to Advanced tab
- Insert *background-repeat:no-repeat;* in the style box

When you save and return, it actually has *background-repeat:no-repeat no-repeat*;

This seems to happen only on table properties. It works just fine (single no-repeat value) on DIV for example. I submitted a bug to ckeditor guys to resolve but I am not sure how long that might take to resolve. My version is 3.6.1 but I can replicate it on ckeditor.com/demo site as well as their latest nightly build.

Did anyone out there come across this issue and worked around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in ckeditor occurring only in webkit. They were able to reproduce it and should fix in future versions.